# Divide a time-ordered set of 3D points into a known number of clusters

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis, k-means, dbscan

I would need to divide a time-ordered set of 3D points into a known number of clusters.

These coordinates correspond to the centroids of images taken by a drone on each blade of a wind turbine.
The drone makes 4 lines along each of the 3 wind turbine blades like this:

[image]

so the total number of image clusters is equal to the total number of lines, i.e. 12.
This is an example of the image coordinates on a wind turbine and the clustering I would like:

[image]

The interval between one photo and another along the blade is fixed, however there may be some spurious shots when the drone moves from one line to another.

I've tried some clustering algorithm in Python like K-means or DBSCAN, but I'm not sure how to deal with spatial coordinates and the relative timestamp together.

Here you will find a .csv with the time and space coordinates of each image in the example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lWZvJ_WH1jp00bLJXhQEw0VxLiDx3z_V/view?usp=share_link